# How do I connect/link 2 or more ADO projects together? Changes in one should be seen in the second

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, ado

I have 2 different ADO projects under the same organization. There is a set of work items that should be in both projects (same items) but only members of the 2nd project will be working on these items. Members of the 1st project still want to see the real time status and updates of these work items but still keep the projects separate. Is there a way to link these projects where if the work items in the 2nd project are updated/modified/changed, then these exact same work items would be automatically updated in the 1st project? Is there a way to link specific work items instead of the entire project?

I played around with the project settings but could not find any options to link another project.

I'm relatively new to ADO so not sure if the capability is there. I tried doing some Googling but all the results were about migration from one project to another. Thanks!